# How do external connection in database at gcloud

Tags: postgresql, gcloud

I've created an instance in compute engine.

I did the installation of postgresql 9.6, , now i'm trying to connect  in external ip using pgadmin client, but it give me an  error

> Connection to 35.224.170.161:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and
>   port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP
>   connections.   Connection to 35.224.170.161:5432 refused. Check that
>   the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting
>   TCP/IP connections.
>       Connection refused: connect
>       Connection refused: connect

I just can to access my database with putty, such as below...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres#connecting-remotely

- open a port in the firewall on Cloud Platform to allow your IP
- Edit pg_hba.conf to allow your IP
- Edit postgresql.conf to listen on *

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm beginner in gcloud.... I already had changed pg_hba and conf, but I had no idea what to do in gcloud.